# Update Select Case Statement in SQL Server:

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have written the below update statement to update the StatusID of the PLN_DU_Vendor table.

```
UPDATE 
PLN_DU_Vendor
SET
    PLN_DU_Vendor.StatusID = 2
FROM
    PLN_DU_Vendor 
INNER JOIN PMT_RFDDetail D ON PLN_DU_Vendor.DUID = D.DUID
INNER JOIN PMT_RFDHeader H ON H.RFDID = D.RFDID AND PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorID = H.VendorID
INNER JOIN PLN_LASCO_Header LH ON LH.LASCOID = H.LASCOID AND LH.ReleaseID = PLN_DU_Vendor.ReleaseID
AND PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity = (D.DespatchQuantity + ISNULL(PLN_DU_Vendor.RFDQuantity, 0))
WHERE
     H.RFDID = 10
```

If the condition

```
PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity = (D.DespatchQuantity + ISNULL(PLN_DU_Vendor.RFDQuantity, 0))
```

fails, I need to update the StatusID as 1. How to do this in the same update select statement.

Comment: What is data type of `PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity`?

Comment: The Datatype of VendorDUQuantity, DespatchQuantity and RFDQuantity are decimal(15,3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to move the condition from the `JOIN` to the assignment as a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE 
PLN_DU_Vendor
SET
    PLN_DU_Vendor.StatusID = CASE 
    WHEN PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity = (D.DespatchQuantity + ISNULL(PLN_DU_Vendor.RFDQuantity, 0))
    THEN 2
    ELSE 1
    END
FROM
    PLN_DU_Vendor 
INNER JOIN PMT_RFDDetail D ON PLN_DU_Vendor.DUID = D.DUID
INNER JOIN PMT_RFDHeader H ON H.RFDID = D.RFDID AND PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorID = H.VendorID
INNER JOIN PLN_LASCO_Header LH ON LH.LASCOID = H.LASCOID AND LH.ReleaseID = PLN_DU_Vendor.ReleaseID
WHERE
     H.RFDID = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare any floating point number whit operator `=`

```
PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity = (D.DespatchQuantity + ISNULL(PLN_DU_Vendor.RFDQuantity, 0))
```

So, it would better to

```
PLN_DU_Vendor.VendorDUQuantity - (D.DespatchQuantity + ISNULL(PLN_DU_Vendor.RFDQuantity, 0)) < ERROR
```